# html input - numbers only AND overwrite mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have HTML input fields that need to limit the input to numbers only as well as set the field to overwrite mode (text is highlighted) when the user clicks or tabs over to the field.

I seem to be able to do one or the other, but not both at the same time.

```
<input type="text" class="numOnly" value="10"> 
    <input type="text" class="numOnly" value="20"> 
        <input type="text" class="numOnly" value="30"> 
            <input type="text" class="numOnly" value="40"> 
<input type="text" class="numOnly" value="50"> 
    <input type="text" class="numOnly" value="60"> 
        <input type="text" class="numOnly" value="70"> 
            <input type="text" class="numOnly" value="80">   

$('.jqndo').keyup(function () {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.-]/gi, "");
});

$(".jqndo").focusin(function(){
    $(this).select();
});
```

What happens is a preliminary set of numbers is entered, then later someone goes back in and corrects them. It would nice if they could just tab across and enter the new numbers without highlighting first.

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/27dkpv3o/6/)

Comment: Handling `keyup` isn’t the right way to filter text. Use an `<input type="number">` if appropriate, or just validate instead of doing active filtering, because working with the selection is really difficult, and you should avoid it at all costs.

Comment: I knew I should of read "what's new in HTML5" all the way through. That's awesome, thanks.

Comment: You can use **input** and **click** event. See the updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yj03csak/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `type="number"` in all the input tags that you want numbered.

And to deny non-number characters use :

```
$(".numOnly").keypress(function(key){
    if(key.charCode < 48 || key.charCode > 57) return false;
});
```

instead of

```
$(".numOnly").keyup(function () {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.-]/g, "");
});
```

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/27dkpv3o/9/)

Reference : http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/10/restricting-input-with-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

You could use *oninput* and *onfocus* events:

```
$(".numOnly").on('input',function () {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.-]/g, "");
});

$(".numOnly").on('focus', function(){
    $(this).select();
});
```